# Circuit Breaker Retry policy for Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function when Cosmos DB throws exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, polly

We're planning to use Circuit Breaker Polly retry in Service Bus Topic trigger Azure Function when Cosmos DB will throw any exception. I have below couple of questions:

1. Can we use circuit breaker retry policy with Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function(v3)? Or is there any alternative available?
2. If yes, please suggest how should we need to integrate circuit breaker polly with service bus topic trigger azure function?

Below is my Azure Function:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber))]
public async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusConfigOptions:EventTypeTopic%", "%ServiceBusConfigOptions:EventTypeTopicSubscription%",
    Connection = "ServiceBusConfigOptions:ConnectionString")]
    string sbMsg)
{
    try
    {   
        var message = sbMsg.AsPoco<CardGroupEvent>();

        _logger.LogInformation("{class} - {method} - {RequestId} - Start",
           nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber), nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber.RunAsync), message.RequestID);

        _logger.LogInformation($"Started processing message {message.AsJson()} with", nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber));

        var validationResult = new CardGroupEventValidator().Validate(message);

        if (validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            await _processor.ProcessAsync(message);
        }
  

        _logger.LogInformation("{class} - {method} - {RequestId} - End",
            nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber), nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber.RunAsync), message.RequestID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Unable to process card group event {sbMsg.AsJson()} with {nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber)}," +
            $" ExceptionMessage:{ex.Message}, StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        throw;
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Below is my Processor:

```
public class CardGroupEventProcessor : ICardGroupEventProcessor
    {
        #region private fields
        private readonly ILogger<CardGroupEventProcessor> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailNotificationPublisher _emailNotificationPublisher;
        private readonly IUINotificationPublisher _uiNotificationPublisher;
        private readonly IRepository<UserSubscriptions> _userSubscriptionrepository;
        private readonly IRepository<AccountSubscriptions> _accountSubscriptionRespository;
        #endregion

        #region ctors
        public CardGroupEventProcessor(ILogger<CardGroupEventProcessor> logger,
            IEmailNotificationPublisher emailNotificationPublisher,
            IUINotificationPublisher uiNotificationPublisher,
            IRepositoryFactory factory)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _emailNotificationPublisher = emailNotificationPublisher;
            _uiNotificationPublisher = uiNotificationPublisher;
            _accountSubscriptionRespository = factory.RepositoryOf<AccountSubscriptions>();
            _userSubscriptionrepository = factory.RepositoryOf<UserSubscriptions>();
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Process card group changed event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="event"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task ProcessAsync(CardGroupEvent @event)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{class} - {method} - {RequestId} - Start",
            nameof(CardGroupEventProcessor), nameof(CardGroupEventProcessor.ProcessAsync), @event.RequestID);

            var eventType = @event.EventType.ToEnum<EventType>();

            var accountSubscriptions = await GetAccountSubscriptionsAsync(@event);

            if (accountSubscriptions.Any())
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Retrieved account subscriptions, requestID:{@event.RequestID}");

                string userUUIDs = string.Join("','", accountSubscriptions.SelectMany(x => x.UUIDs));

                var userSubscriptions = await GetUserSubscriptionsAsync(userUUIDs, eventType);

                if (userSubscriptions.Any())
                {
                    await _uiNotificationPublisher.PublishAsync(userSubscriptions, @event);

                    await _emailNotificationPublisher.PublishEmailAsync(userSubscriptions, @event);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"No User subscriptions found for EventType:{@event.EventType}," +
                        $" accountNumber:{@event.AccountNumber}, requestID:{@event.RequestID}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"No UI/Email subscriptions found for accountNumber:{@event.AccountNumber}, requestID:{@event.RequestID}");
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("{class} - {method} - {RequestId} - End",
           nameof(CardGroupEventProcessor), nameof(CardGroupEventProcessor.ProcessAsync), @event.RequestID);
        }

        #endregion

        #region private methods
        private async Task<IEnumerable<AccountSubscriptions>> GetAccountSubscriptionsAsync(CardGroupEvent @event)
        {
            var result = await _accountSubscriptionRespository
                .GetByQueryAsync($"SELECT * FROM asub WHERE asub.Account ='{@event.AccountNumber}' " +
                $"AND asub.Payer = '{@event.PayerNumber}' " +
                $"AND asub.Active=1");

            return result;
        }
        private async Task<IEnumerable<UserSubscriptions>> GetUserSubscriptionsAsync(string UserUUIDs, EventType eventType)
        {
            var result = await _userSubscriptionrepository
                .GetByQueryAsync($"SELECT * FROM usub WHERE usub.Type='Subscription' " +
                $"AND usub.UUID IN('{UserUUIDs}') " +
                $"AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(usub.Events,{{'EventType':{(int)eventType}}},true)");

            return result;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Below is my Startup.cs class:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace CardGroupEventSubscriber
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            
            builder.Services.AddCosmosRepository(options =>
            {
                options.SerializationOptions = new Microsoft.Azure.CosmosRepository.Options.RepositorySerializationOptions
                {
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.Default
                };
            });

            

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBusFactory, AzureServiceBusFactory>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(ICardGroupEventProcessor), typeof(CardGroupEventProcessor));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IUINotificationPublisher), typeof(UINotificationPublisher));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IEmailNotificationPublisher), typeof(EmailNotificationPublisher));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function would you like to decorate with the resilience policies?

Comment: As far as I understand your question I would say that no it is not feasible. The primary reason is that your Azure function instances are **not sharing the circuit breaker**. Each instance would have its own circuit breaker, which kills the whole point of having a circuit breaker (short-cuts the execution if the downstream system is observed as temporarily unavailable). In each instance you have to reach the unsuccess requests threshold to open the circuit.

Comment: @PeterCsala I want to add circuit breaker policy for Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure function(which is also mentioned in the question)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough, let me try to rephrase it. Which C# method / function call would you like to decorate with a policy?

Comment: @PeterCsala This is the function name "CardGroupEventSubscriber" mentioned in the top. Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function

Comment: Ohh so you want to decorate the entire function rather than just some part of your logic. Can I ask you why?

Comment: @PeterCsala, No actually I want to decorate only the part where I am calling Cosmos DB, so if cosmos db throwing any error only then I want to retry. And i am thinking we need to do that, we need to decorate the entire function

Comment: There is one article(https://medium.com/@piotrkarpaa/building-resilient-azure-functions-with-retry-policies-281cb07da362), which is showing we need to use "ExponentialBackoffRetry" attribute to achive retry policy in Azure Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function. Is that correct approach?

Comment: As it is stated in the article depending on the trigger you might need to use different retry logic. Polly is good for Http based triggers or for downstream system calls.

Comment: I would suggest to check out the built in retry capabilities first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#retry-policies-preview.

Comment: If you want to make your Cosmos db calls are more resilent then you should first try to rely on the SDK's built-in capabilites and then try to explore Polly